# Laravel - How to get the guard that authenticated the user?

Tags: laravel

I have a customized LoginController with two functions:

> loginCustomer that runs Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(...);
>
> loginEmployee that runs Auth::guard('employee')->attempt(...);

I have customized two guards in config.auth that points to my two Models (Customer and Employee) and protect the routes of backoffice and frontend.

Now in my customized LogoutController i want to run Auth::logout() but it doesn't work because i think it uses the default guard.

It only works if i specify `Auth::guard('customer')->logout()` or `Auth::guard('employee')->logout()`, depending the guard that was used to login.

Is there any way to get the guard used to authenticate the user so i can use only `Auth::guard($guard)->logout`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not be the perfect solution, but it works. Basically, just go through all the guards and check if the user is authenticated by that guard. If he is - log him out. Be aware that this will log him out of all the guards he is logged in to.

This code would go to your logout controller:

```
  $guards = array_keys(config('auth.guards'));
  foreach ($guards as $guard) {
    if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) Auth::guard($guard)->logout();
  }
```

Comment: it's not the perfect solution, because it doesn't return the guard, but it solves the main goal that was making the logout

Answer (score 8):

You can use `shouldUse` method:

After the call of this method you can logout user via guard you was previously set by `shouldUse` method.

In your case:

```
if( Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(...) ){
    Auth::shouldUse('customer');
}


if( Auth::guard('employee')->attempt(...) ){
    Auth::shouldUse('employee');
}
```

After this you can use Auth::logout and previously choosen guard (via `shouldUse`) will be used:

```
// just use Auth::logout without Auth::guard(GUARDNAME)->logout()
Auth::logout();
```

Short documentation about this method: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.html#method_shouldUse

Comment: I've tried your solution but it didn't worked in the LougoutController. But it worked in the login functions so i added Auth::shouldUse('customer') before the attempt and changed Auth::guard('customer')-attempt(...) to Auth::atempt(...)

Comment: I made additional tests and realized that your solution works by moving the logout function from the LogoutController to the LoginController.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.