# How to Get Auth::User() Array Elements Value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to get array elements value in Auth::User(). After 
`{{dd(Auth::User()}}` output of array shows many elements:

```
  Admin {#474 ▼
  #guard: "admin"
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
```

I'm trying to access using `Auth::user()->guard;` this but it does not work for me. Please tell me how to get this. Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - How to get the guard that authenticated the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809403/laravel-how-to-get-the-guard-that-authenticated-the-user)

Comment: That property isn't visible because it's protected or private. Look into oop visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this function. It checks the current logged in user against all guard. Here I used dd to dump the logged in guard. But you can extract and utilize it to do whatever you want.

```
  $guards = array_keys(config('auth.guards'));
  foreach ($guards as $guard) {
    if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) dd($guard);
  }
```